# Spotify Track Clone

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, spotify

I am trying to clone the [Web Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/browse/featured), my project is in [Github](https://github.com/524119574/spotify-clone). The framework that I've been using is Vue.js.

Now I am trying to clone [this page](https://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX4E3UdUs7fUx), where user can click on the track and the corresponding track in the playlist will be played. Now I can get an object for each track, and there is a `preview url`, e.g. `"preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/4839b070015ab7d6de9fec1756e1f3096d908fba",` and I can used the audio tag to play the preview of the music.

The problem is that I don't know how to play the given track when the corresponding play button is clicked.

```
<track-display v-for="track in tracks" :track-title="TITLE" :artist="artist" :album="ALBUM"></track-display>
```

`track-display` is an component that I created which is suppose to contain track title, artists and album, which looks like:
[image]

Now, I have an array `tracks` which stores all the track-objects. How am I going to detect which track element is clicked and play the corresponding track?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Vue.js [Custom event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events). And also you will need to accept an additional argument `trackNum`, so that the parent knows which track is been clicked. You code should change to something like this:

```
<track-display v-for="(track, index) in tracks" :track-title="TITLE" :artist="artist" :album="ALBUM" :trackNum="index"></track-display>
```

And when you emit the event you will need something like:

```
methods: {
  togglePlayState() { this.$emit('togglePlay', trackNum); },
}
```

The you will need to catch the event in parent and play the corresponding `preview-url` in the `tracks` array, since the `trackNum` is corresponding to the position in `tracks`.